# WPF how to bind self-referential dataset to a treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, dataset

I am a total beginner in WPF. I would like to bind the following `DataSet` containing nodes and relations to a `TreeView`. The dataset is:

```
internal static DataSet getData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("data");
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("ParentId", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("NodeDescription");

    dt.Rows.Add(1, null, "Employees");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, null, "Cars");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, 1, "Men");
    dt.Rows.Add(4, 1, "Women");
    dt.Rows.Add(5, 2, "BMW");
    dt.Rows.Add(6, 2, "Lexus");
    dt.Rows.Add(7, 3, "Adam Kowalski");
    dt.Rows.Add(8, 3, "Dawid Nowacki");
    dt.Rows.Add(9, 4, "Ilona Wacek");

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    //add a relationship

    ds.Relations.Add("rsParentChild"
    ,ds.Tables["data"].Columns["Id"]
    ,ds.Tables["data"].Columns["ParentId"]);

    return ds;
}
```

I would like to have:

[image]

Now I achieve this by resursive retrieveing all datatable and ading nodes to the treeview. However, I hope there is a direct `XAML` binding.

I'd like to add that the dataset will be dynamically changing and there might many nesting levels. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that works :

**Code-behind**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var dataSet = getData();
        _rootNodes = dataSet.Tables["data"].DefaultView;
        _rootNodes.RowFilter = "ParentId IS NULL";
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private DataView _rootNodes;
    public DataView RootNodes
    {
        get { return _rootNodes; }
    }

    internal static DataSet getData()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

**XAML**

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootNodes}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding rsParentChild}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeDescription}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: How can I achive this with a List of objects as a DataSource? I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161963/how-to-bind-self-referencing-table-to-wpf-treeview but I am unable to understand the converter mentioned there.