# How to bind Self-referencing table to WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, treeview

What is the best solution to bind a self-referncing table from edmx like:

[image]

to a WPF `TreeView` control to have something like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve the problem using this `Binding Converter`:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var item = value as MyTable;
        return  item.MyTable1.Where(i => i.parent_id== item.id); //return children
    }
```

.xaml :

```
<TreeView Name="treeview1" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource HierarchyConverter}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" >
      <TreeView.Resources>
            <local:HierarchyConverter x:Key="HierarchyConverter" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource HierarchyConverter}}">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding element_name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

.cs :

```
treeview1.ItemsSource = db.MyTable.Where(x => x.partnt_id== null);//elements that have no parent
```

Comment: Could you explain where the convert function is implemented? Do you have a custom converter class which implements IValueConverter or something?

Comment: And an explenation on the 'MyTable' Object would also be nice. I am sorry, I am not able to reprduce your answer in this state.

Comment: Yes. I have a custom converter class which implements IValueConverter with first Convert function. 
The  'MyTable' Object was something like the table that shown in question body with Id and Parent_id columns.

Answer (score 1):

Josh Smith has an excellent [article on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) that walks you through how to craft a view model that your `TreeView` can bind to.  You'll not get away with just using the EF because EF doesn't do recursion.