# Hide TreeView items which already shown in parent-child hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to show the content of DataTable with self-parent relation in TreeView. The problem is that there is duplication of DataTable records which have ancestors: they are shown as parent items and as members of hierarchy:

[image: TreeView]

I want to show items only once: in hierarchy.

Window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingTreeViewToDataSet.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingTreeViewToDataSet"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="DataSetProvider" MethodName="CreateDataSet" ObjectType="{x:Type local:DataSetCreator}" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TreeView Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{StaticResource DataSetProvider}" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Parent2Child}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Dataset:

```
public static class DataSetCreator
{
    public static DataSet CreateDataSet()
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();

        var tbl = new DataTable("Data");
        tbl.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        tbl.Columns.Add("ParentID", typeof(int));
        tbl.Columns.Add("Name");

        ds.Tables.Add(tbl);
        ds.Relations.Add("Parent2Child", tbl.Columns["ID"], tbl.Columns["ParentID"]);

        tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0, DBNull.Value, "Parent#1" });
        tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 0, "Child#2" });
        tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 1, "Subchild#3" });

        return ds;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are taking the wrong approach to fix your problem. Your *actual* problem is that you have duplicate data elements in your collection. Instead of compounding the problem by not addressing it and just hiding the invalid elements, why not just fix your data and remove the duplicate elements?

Comment: Could you explain? In the example there are only 3 records in DataTable, but 6 nodes in TreeView. I don't understand how I could fix data.

Comment: If you don't want the duplicate items to appear in the `TreeView` then don't add them into the data bound data source collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed approach and filter data source like described here [WPF how to bind self-referential dataset to a treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212568/wpf-how-to-bind-self-referential-dataset-to-a-treeview)

thank you, @Sheridan :)