# F# - WPF treeview - bind self referencing dataset using XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, f#, treeview

I'm not very familiar with WPF, and I use it with F#.
The scenario is that I have a dataset with parentID that I'd like to display in a treeview. (For the little story, the rows are snapshots coming from a scvmm VM)

I have a working code that uses an enumerator of the dataset and populates the treeview, however I'd like to use a XAML binding instead.
I found [WPF how to bind self-referential dataset to a treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212568/wpf-how-to-bind-self-referential-dataset-to-a-treeview) that deals with the exact same in C#, but it uses partial classes that I'm unable to directly translate into F#.

Is this possible, did I follow the wrong avenue trying to translate the above solution, or am I simply missing knowledge on F#/WPF internals?

Thanks a bunch for any pointer!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

You can use the answer which you provided in the link by binding the Window's ViewModel (DataContext) using XAML. Check this question: [How do I set a ViewModel on a window in XAML using DataContext property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590446/how-do-i-set-a-viewmodel-on-a-window-in-xaml-using-datacontext-property)

Then implement the view model's properties with F# according to the question you found ([How do I set a ViewModel on a window in XAML using DataContext property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590446/how-do-i-set-a-viewmodel-on-a-window-in-xaml-using-datacontext-property)) and then you should be to able to do use the XAML binding.

**WPF + F# in general**

In general using XAML, WPF and F# only is a bad combination because of the lack of partial classes in F#. Usually i write views (WPF/XAML project) with C# and view models with F#.